# i try to get url and id using python but mu code can;t do this plzz anyone solve this

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to get url and id using python, but my code can't do this:

```
from requests import get
# from selenium import webdriver
import requests
# url = requests.GET.get('id')

def get_real_url_from_shortlink(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return resp.url
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected URL that would be passed!
Also, you can delete "from requests import get " because you are importing the whole package in the second line. However, if you want to keep the first line, then remove the second one and inside your method type directly "resp = get(url)"

Answer (score 0):

It might just be the formatting on this site but your indentation is incorrect.
you should have :

```
def get_real_url_from_shortlink(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return resp.url
```